# Root domain config overriding subdomain config

Tags: database, config, multi-environment, subdomain

My question is similar to [Subdomain database configuration picking up root domain config](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5232/subdomain-database-configuration-picking-up-root-domain-config), but I don't have any custom database variables.

I have a staging site and a (forthcoming) production site on the same remote shared hosting server. The staging site is at a `staging` subdomain and the production site will be at the root.

The staging site seems to be using the config variables from the root domain in `general.php` and `db.php`. I had to take the production site out of `db.php` to get the staging site to work at all, and anywhere I'm using environment variables (like my asset paths), they're coming from the production config instead.

This is my `general.php`:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,
    'loginPath' => 'admin',
  ),
  'localhost' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => 'C:\wamp\www\craftcms',
      'baseUrl'  => 'localhost/craftcms/',
    )
  ),
  'staging.safs.msu.edu' => array(
        'server' => '35.8.12.67',
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => 'staging',
      'baseUrl'  => 'http://staging.safs.msu.edu',
    ),
  ),
  'safs.msu.edu' => array(
    'server' => '35.8.12.67',
    'devMode' => false,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => '',
      'baseUrl'  => 'http://safs.msu.edu',
    ),
  ),
);
```

**How do I get my config files to recognize the staging subdomain's settings?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft looks for partial matches to apply config settings (both `general.php` and `db.php` which means you can do things like:

```
'.dev' => array(
.. 

'.com' => array(
..
```

Craft applies these settings for each match from the top of the file to the bottom. So in your case because you have the the production domain after your subdomain config it matches and overrides your subdomain settings.

Simply swap your config variables over and it'll work.

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,
    'loginPath' => 'admin',
  ),
  'localhost' => array(
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => 'C:\wamp\www\craftcms',
      'baseUrl'  => 'localhost/craftcms/',
    )
  ),
  'safs.msu.edu' => array(
    'server' => '35.8.12.67',
    'devMode' => false,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => '',
      'baseUrl'  => 'http://safs.msu.edu',
    ),
  ),
  'staging.safs.msu.edu' => array(
    'server' => '35.8.12.67',
    'devMode' => true,
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => 'staging',
      'baseUrl'  => 'http://staging.safs.msu.edu',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, when I do that, the config variables seem not to be recognized at all. DevMode is not turned on for the staging site, and my asset paths contain `{baseUrl}` instead of `http://safs.msu.edu` like they did when they were using the root domain settings.

Comment: Yeah - stupid mistake by me - updated answer with the solution :)

Comment: There we go! I should have tried switching the order - makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to put the settings for the Production site under the wildcard settings '*' and then overwrite any for dev and staging below that.